# Python pass multiple values while using multiprocessing and itertools

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-itertools

I am trying to use multiprocessing to do some calculation on the combinations gernerated by itertools.
Here is a simple version of what I am doing:

```
import multiprocessing
import itertools
def func(comb):
    x=list(comb)[0]
    y=zs[x]
    return x+y
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cores=multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cores)
    xs=range(50)
    ys=range(50)
    zs=[iy+1 for iy in ys]
    for r in pool.imap(func,itertools.product(xs,ys)):
        print(r)
```

But it raises an error:

> NameError: name 'zs' is not defined

How to pass `zs` to `func` while using `itertools.product`?

Thanks a lot for any comments.

Comment: You would need to pass `zs` to `func`. Calling `global zs` in `func` might also work, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Comment: @Ahndwoo No, at least not on every platform because the `zs` on module level is defined in the main file guard and that isn't executed on windows in the spawned subrocesses.  But global variables are a bad idea anyway.  A function/method should get everything it needs beyond constants as argument(s).

Comment: @BlackJack I figured that might be the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use partial function to set partial parameters of a function like below

```py
from functools import partial

def func(comb, zs):
    print(comb, zs)

pfunc = partial(func, zs="abc")

pfunc("123")

# 123 abc
```